# css, js версии в Django

Tags: django

Какие существуют способы для нумерации версий css, js в django?

Comment: Объясните подробнее в тексте вопроса (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/789758/edit)), какую задачу вы решаете и зачем их именно нумеровать (я немного догадываюсь зачем, но всё же стоит описать это в вопросе явно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) обеспечивает и версионирование.