# Django кэширование

Tags: django, кэширование

расскажите пожалуйста, как бороться с кэшированием css в Django? После изменений css только жесткий ребут браузеров помогает. В какую сторону копать? Спасибо!

Comment: по-моему `Ctrl-F5` не есть уж жесткий ребут при локальной разработке. Или у вас вопрос про продакшн? Если, да укажите через что у вас работает сам Django

Comment: Работаю в pycharm, потом заливаю изменения в github, а на сервере git pull. Я на этапе продакшена, мелких изменений все равно много. Вот и пытаюсь понять, можно ли это временно победить

Comment: если у вас на стороне сервера nginx, [гляньте сюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/428127/), статейка по управлению кэшем. Либо в самом браузере отключать. Инструменты разработчика -> сеть-> выключить кэш

Comment: Это вопрос не к джанго, а к браузеру. Отключите у себя кэширование. На проде используйте разные имена файлов

Comment: Проблема в том, что у примерно 50 машинок придется браузер ковырять. А есть ли способ сбросить кэш через консоль сервера, вроде не что подобное было в bitrix?

Comment: @user444826 Попробуйте поиграть с http заголовком Cache-Control https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Выставляйте жёсткие ограничения в заголовке Cache-Control или переименовывайте файл при каждом изменении. А ещё лучше используйте системы сборки типа Webpack, которые могут автоматически переименовывать получаемые бандлы при каждом изменении и дают кучу других плюшек

Answer (score 0):

Читал, что [`django-compressor`](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/) помимо сжатия, генерирует файл с уникальным именем, что решит вашу проблему

Вот подтверждение ответа - [css, js версии в Django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789758/css-js-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-django/789808#789808)

Answer (score 0):

На mac os отлично помогает "COMMAND" + "SHIFT" + "R".

Страничка обновляется с новыми css.

Comment: Просить каждого из тысяч/миллионов/миллиардов пользователей нажать Cmd+Shift+R - мягко говоря, сомнительный подход